# cant drag floor point in archipack

Tags: archipack-add-on

**Problem**

When I create a new floor and manipulate it, I cannot drag freely the white dot (the parts).

**What I tried**

I created a new file and in the new file it works fine. But I did a lot of work on this file.

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11rFEK9CheAtiwRr7i2GnOei1ReeaDO5y/view?usp=sharing)

[image: The dote im trying to move]

Comment: can u provide your blend file?

Comment: yes i edited the post

Comment: ok, on my machine (mac) on different versions of blender -whenever i add a floor -> blenders stops working at all :(

Answer (score 1):

I tried an approach that often works for me in recovering from blender trickery ;-)

I started a new blend app session, "File :: Append" the old file, and things started working again.   As I had only a lowly 16 GB RAM, I set 3d-view to solid (not Material Preview) as compiling the Material renders would blow my memory limit.

With this workaround, there's no telling how many times you may need to recover, as you'll need to report this bug to the Archipack community.

[image]